# Add the bookmarks bar to internal browsers of iPad apps

Tags: ipad, bookmarks

Apps like Twitterific and Flipboard are great but I want to be able to use the "Offline Pages" app to save the text of a link so I can read it later. In Twitterific, when I touch a link it opens in an internal web app that doesn't have the bookmarks bar and therefor doesn't have my "Offline Pages" bookmarklet.

I read somewhere that Instapaper has better integration with apps like Twitterific but I haven't seen anywhere how it works and I really do like offline pages . . . it does exactly what I want! Any ideas?

I know I can simply "open in Safari" but that's another page load and I loose my place in Flipboard or Twitterific and have to re-open the app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way for developers to integrate your bookmarks into our apps. We create a browser using WebKit, but the bookmarks are stored in Safari, not WebKit. Instapaper is likely your best choice, and is available in most RSS apps and many Twitter apps do (including Echofon). You then can view these saved pages from the Instapaper app anytime you want.

Answer (score 1):

Instapaper is a web & desktop service that allows you to save, on your iDevice, an offline copy of articles or web pages and read them later.

Personally, I use [Read it Later](http://readitlaterlist.com/) (more or less the same thing as Instapaper, but with less applications integration) and if I remember correctly, both work in the same way (at least with RIL) :

- Click on a bookmarklet or other
- The webpage is uploaded to Instapaper's servers
- You use your application to download the offline copy

So, you can see that you do not directly download the offline copy on your device.

Instapaper is integrated with several applications like Twitterrific, Twitter for iPhone, Flipboard and others iOS & Mac OS.

Moreover, Instapaper is compatible with iPad, iPhone and Mac OS.

I'd recommend you [a nice review about Instapaper](http://smokingapples.com/featured/instapaper/).